# Entity Framework - Run function after properties are populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, properties, lazy-loading

Is there a way to populate properties after Entity Framework has loaded the entity?

For example - I have an object that has a couple of non-mapped properties that I need to populate after Entity Framework has loaded all of the other properties. I tried to put the logic to populate the properties into the constructor but it is running before any of the other properties are populated so they all read as `null`.

```
public class Planet 
{
    public Planet()
    {
        //this does not work because the Structures
        //and Ships properties return null
        GetAllResourceGatherers(); 
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Structure> Structures { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ship> Ships { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int GatherRate {get; private set;}

    public void GetAllResourceGatherers
    {
       var resourceGatherers = Ships.OfType<IResourceGatherer>().ToList();  
       resourceStorers.AddRange(Structures.OfType<IResourceStorer>().ToList());
       foreach (var gatherer in resourceGatherers)
       {
          gatherRate += gatherer.GatherRate;
       }
    }
}
```

To try to avoid the issue with navigation properties not loading in time I tried to force it by changing the `GetAllResourceGatherers()` method to:

```
public void GetAllResourceGatherers
{ 
   using (var db = new DbContext())
   {
      //This does not work because the 'Id' property comes back.
      //as 0 which is just default
      Structures = db.Structures.Where(x => x.ParentId == Id).ToList();
      Ships = db.Ships.Where(x => x.ParentId == Id).ToList();

      var resourceGatherers = Ships.OfType<IResourceGatherer>().ToList();   
      resourceStorers.AddRange(Structures.OfType<IResourceStorer>().ToList());

      foreach (var gatherer in resourceGatherers)
      {
         gatherRate += gatherer.GatherRate;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: _navigation properties not loading in time_ will always be an issue if you try to do this automatically when the object is materialized. You can't force eager loading to happen by default, so you'll always have to think of it wherever you query the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no onload event where you could execute your code.

However you could make the GatherRate a function. (with a possible check to only compute the rate if a private variable is set to null

```
[NotMapped]
private int? _GaterRate;

public int GaterRate() {
    if (!_GaterRate.HasValue)
        GaterRate = GetAllResourceGatherers();//this would have to return the GatherRate of course;

    return _GaterRate.Value;
 }
```

you could even make it in a special get function this way to be computed when GaterRate is null (called the first time 1 would presume)

Comment: I ended up implementing something like this. Instead of a function I simply put it in the getter for the property. I also made a `[NotMapped]` bool property to indicate that it has populated the fields seeing as I have multiple GatherRates.